# How to listen only to specific events in inotifywait?

Tags: linux, bash, centos, inotify, inotifywait

Can someone explain why `inotifywait` still reports about opened files, when I have excluded open?

```
mkdir /tmp/a

inotifywait --exclude acess,attrib,close_write,close_nowrite,close,open,moved_to,moved_from,move,delete,delete_self,unmount -r -m /tmp/a/

touch /tmp/a/test
/tmp/a/ OPEN test
/tmp/a/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE test
```

All I am interested in is if new files are made or current files are modified.

I use CentOS 7, if that changes anything.

Comment: `--exclude` is for excluding matching *filenames*.  It doesn't have anything to do with excluding particular events.  See the `inotifywait` man page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-e` event (Listen for specific event(s) only) is different from the `--exclude <pattern>` which is meant for not processing any events whose filename matches the specified regular expression. Your actual command needed to be without `open` on the list of `events` to watch on. For e.g. if you are interested in only `create` and `modify` just do

```
inotifywait -rme create,modify /tmp/a/
```

[inotifywait(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait)